# Why do i keep getting Stackoverflow Error in Sudoku Solver C#

Tags: c#, recursion, runtime-error, stack-overflow, sudoku

EDIT: I'm actually so sorry. My mistake was there

```
    //get unassigned position 
    unassignedPos = GetNextUnassignedValue(matrix);
    int col = unassignedPos.Item1;
    int row = unassignedPos.Item2;
```

row must be item1 and col must be item2... Also found out that i tried it with an sudoku that couldn't be solved correctly.

I'm new to C# and just starting to get into coding more deeply. Does anyone know why I keep getting Stackoverflow Errors in the following code sample? I double checked and rearranged the constraints, they should be fine.

```
    class SudokuCalc
{
    (int, int) finish = (9, 9);
    (int, int) unassignedPos = (0, 0);

    //method to recursively solve the sudoku
    public bool Solve(int[,] matrix)
    {
        //if we are at the finish position return true
        if (finish.Item1 == GetNextUnassignedValue(matrix).Item1
            && finish.Item2 == GetNextUnassignedValue(matrix).Item2)
        {
            return true;
        }
        //get unassigned position 
        unassignedPos = GetNextUnassignedValue(matrix);
        int col = unassignedPos.Item1;
        int row = unassignedPos.Item2;

        //go through all possible values
        for (int value = 1; value <= 9; value++)
        {
            if (IsValid(matrix, row, col, value))
            {
                matrix[row, col] = value;
                //recursively try to solve
                if (Solve(matrix))
                {
                    return true;
                }
                // if we couldnt solve the sudoku
                // set the previous value 0 and try again
                matrix[row, col] = 0;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code line by line and watching what it's really doing?

Comment: Any chance you can post a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

In current situation StackOverflow exception means your `Solve` method called itself too much times recursively. When that happens, you can stop debugger and see all stack trace with lots of nested `Solve` calls.

You have some edge case in your conditions that force code to call `Solve` method infinitely. To trace that you can add logging in beginning of `Solve` method and write to disk matrix that your is called with. Probably at some point you'll get same value over and over again.